# Making elements visible / invisible using asynctask OnPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, visible

I'm using AsyncTask to grab a web feed. When the activity is set up I'm displaying these elements in activity_main as visible as a splash screen...

```
 android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
 android:id="@+id/loading_label"
```

Then once the asynctask has executed I want these GONE and to make other elements visible:

```
 android:id="@+id/login_label"
 android:id="@+id/login_textbox"
```

How do I correctly set visibility in my onPostExecute, this is what I've tried...

```
protected void onPostExecute(String retval) {
    progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    loading_label.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    login_label.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    login_textbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

But I get the error...
"Multiple markers at this line
    - progressBar1 cannot be resolved
    - View cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Do you define `progressBar1` and the others as fields and initialize them in `onCreate`? At some point you need to do `ProgressBar progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1)` to initialize that variable, for example.

Comment: So I added the following inside my OnCreate
`ProgressBar progressBar1 = (ProgressBar);`
`findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);`
But I get this error:  
_Multiple markers at this line
 - ProgressBar cannot be resolved to a type
 - ProgressBar cannot be resolved to a variable_

Comment: Check your `import` statements (or type `Ctrl + Shift + O` in Eclipse). You need to import `android.view.View` for `View.GONE` and `android.widget.ProgressBar` for `ProgressBar`.

Comment: I get it, all on the same line...
`ProgressBar progressBar1 =( ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);`

Comment: All working except for this ...
`Button login_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);`

Answer (score 3):

It's because those variables are not within the scope of your AsyncTask class. An easy way to do this would be to write a function in your Activity that sets the visibilities, then call that function from onPostExecute.

Comment: OK so I added this to my MainActivity.java:
`public void switchScreens() {
    progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    loading_label.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    login_label.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    login_textbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}`  
But I get the error for each line _progressBar1 cannot be resolved_

Comment: where did you declare and initialize progressBar1?

Comment: Set it up in...

activity_main.xml

Comment: if I have a function in MainActivity:  
`public void updateSpinner(ArrayList schoolNames)`  
How do I call this function from a class fetchSchools.java where I have my AsyncTask?

Comment: @rihallix Defining the view in XML doesn't automatically make a variable for you. Defining `android:id="@+id/progressBar1"` in XML creates the Java constant `R.id.progressBar1`, and you need to use `findViewById()` with this constant if you want access to the `View` object from your Java code; see my comment on your question.